# How to Configure WEM-MX meter for energy tracking

Tags: php, soap, solar

As a warning this is a bit of a hectic endeavor. At work I'm trying to get a power meter to report its usage data. The meter that I am using is from this website http://www.energytracking.com/ (WEM-MX) this is a very old and outdated site, with very poor documentation. Supposedly this device is capable of Reporting via FTP and/or using SOAP Web services. I have been trying to reverse engineer what I can given the documentation that they have listed but I'm not sure how to progress. Currently, I have gotten the meter to connect via http to a webserver I have running PHP. I have no experience using SOAP or XML so I'm not sure what to do next.
Supposedly the Meter is sending POST headers to my PHP page, but whenever it 'connects' the php page does not appear to run.

---

Below is a link to the given 'sample' request and response
http://etanalytics.com/ETWSMeter/service1.asmx?op=ReportData

---

I know this is vague, but I'm not sure what information is/isn't relevant.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?  I.e. are you in a position to answer your own question?  I’m just getting into this stuff and have several WEM-MX modules we may be replacing.